# Non-blocking MySQL updates with java?

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, asynchronous, c3p0

For a multiplayer game I'm working on I'd like to record events to the mysql database without blocking the game update thread so that if the database is busy or a table is locked the game doesn't stop running while it waits for a write.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

I'm using c3p0 to manage the database connection pool. My best idea so far is to add query update strings to a synchronized list with an independent thread checking the list every 100ms and executing the queries it finds there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My best idea so far is to add query update strings to a synchronized list with an independent thread checking the list every 100ms and executing the queries it finds there.

This sounds good to me if you don't want to block your main thread, except that don't use synchronized list and 100ms polling, but use some [BlockingQueue](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) implementation instead. [LinkedBlockingQueue](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) should do the job, if you make it unbounded it will never block your main thread.

Answer (score 2):

Place updates on a `BlockingQueue`. Have a separate thread wait on the queue with `take()`, followed by `drainTo()` to consume all pending updates and push them to the server in one go. Use a single multi-row INSERT for maximum efficiency.

This approach ensures that updates hit the server without any gratuitous delay due to polling frequency, while making chunkier, and thus more efficient, requests as volume climbs.

Answer (score 0):

I think an "INSERT DELAYED" might be what you're looking for, as the INSERT returns immediately, and MySQL will handle all the threading issues for you.  There is no equivalent UPDATE statement, however, so you'd need to rewrite your code so you're only using INSERTs or REPLACEs.

Comment: If i remember correctly, Insert delayed only works with myisam an not with innodb. Make sure you are happy with this.